# How can traditional edge detection algorithms be implemented on a GPU?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, gpu, edge-detection, canny-edge-detector

How can edge detection algorithms, which are not based on deep learning, such as the canny edge detector, be implemented on a GPU? For example, how are non-edge pixels removed from an image once it detects all the edges?

The reason why I am asking this question is that when writing data to memory the GPU cores can't see what memory locations the other cores are writing to, so I am interested in knowing how traditional edge detectors can be implemented in on GPU.